# Why there is no Javalike semaphore acquiring multiple permits in C#?

Tags: c#, concurrency

Why there is no method for acquiring multiple permits on semaphore in C#? I want to use my semaphore like this:

```
semaphore.Acquire(2);
```

Comment: Is your question how to do it or is your question "why doesn't it work like in Java". To get answers to the first, you need to rephrase your question. You won't get answers to the second.

Comment: Actually I can take a pretty guess at the second: "Because the C# development team thought about this long and hard, and have found some pretty good reasons not to do it like in Java". Or the more or less equivalent but slightly less friendly "because it's probably one of those not-so-well-thought-through Java features that everyone just uses out of habit".

Comment: @CompuChip: Actually it's probably neither. The C# development team doesn't even implement library functions. And the feature is probably not used often enough to warrant the work needed to implement by the .Net team.

Comment: Good point @Gabe. +1 for your answer that explains this too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good api design is a fine art, truly mastered only by a few.  One important aspect is to emphasize commonality.  The .NET Semaphore class has that, you use `WaitOne()` to acquire the semaphore.  Like you do on all of the synchronization classes.

And it becomes especially a fine art by knowing what to **leave out**.  A custom `Aquire(n)` method would be high on that cut list.  It is a very troublesome method, the underlying native implementation on Windows doesn't support it either.  Which produces the serious risk of inducing deadlock that's next to impossible to debug, the code would be hung inside an invisible method that's looping, buried deep inside the CLR.  Which adds lots of semantics to waits that matter a great deal when code needs to be aborted.  You're free to loop yourself, a simple workaround and of course well visible when you debug a deadlock, you can at least inspect the counter.

Answer (score 4):

The .Net [`Semaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) object is a wrapper around the Win32 [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx) object. Since the Win32 semaphores don't have any mechanism to acquire multiple resources at once, there is no easy way to provide it in the .Net Framework.

Of course it's possible that Microsoft could have implemented their own abstraction over Win32 semaphores, but then they couldn't be included in a [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx) call. It's quite likely that MS never even considered implementing this feature.

Comment: They could have added it to SemaphoreSlim but it seem that they mainly kept the API of the Semaphore class for it.

Answer (score 1):

You may write your own [extention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) method to **Semaphore** class:

```
namespace Extentions
{
    public static class SemaphoreExtentions
    {

        public static void Acquire(this Semaphore semaphore, int permits)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i < permits; ++i)
               semaphore.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using Extentions;

//...

public void SomeMethod()
{
    var sem = new Semaphore(10, 10);
    sem.Acquire(6);
}
```

**Update**
To avoid deadlocks:

```
public static void Acquire(this Semaphore semaphore, int permits)
{
    lock (semaphore)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < permits; ++i)
            semaphore.WaitOne();        
    }
}
```

Of course you shouldn't lock this semaphore somewhere else because it may cause deadlocks too. Another option is to change signature of the method to **Acquire(this Semaphore semaphore, int permits, object sync)** and lock **sync** object.

Comment: You should lock whole Acquire method body (consider two threads acquiring permits at the same time). That is ok, but I just really want to know that "pretty good reasons" why there is no counting semaphore out of the box in C#.

Comment: This will cause deadlocks. In your example, what happens if you have 2 clients and the both try to acquire 6 at the same time? Say they both acquire 5 -- then they will both wait for each other to give up the last 1.

Comment: I think Semaphore's owner object must worry about thread-safety of his members.

Comment: @Gabe Are you about my answer or about Mixer's commet?

Comment: My comment is about the answer. Mixer's comment is suggesting a way to avoid the deadlock.

Comment: `lock (semaphore)` is not good idea. Need a lock object that is *only* locked by callers trying to acquire a given semaphore, e.g. `readonly object acquireLock = new object();` ... `lock (acquireLock) ...` REASON: `Acquire` may hold this lock a **long** time, as it accumulates enough permits. Suppose code elsewhere wishes to `lock (semaphore)` for some other purpose - it will be stuck waiting for this code. **UNFORTUNATELY**, passing in a `sync` object, may cause the **opposite** problem: two different callers, with different sync objects for same semaphore, may deadlock. ...

Comment: ... I think this can only be safely solved by creating a new class that WRAPS the Semaphore [Semaphore is a sealed class, so can’t subclass it], with two fields: a Semaphore and the acquireLock. Then we can be assured that all `Acquire`s on a given Semaphore are using the same lock, and that no one else is using that lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to check if the permits are available, and do not need to block, this can be implemented in a simple and safe (free of deadlocks) manner.

```
public static bool Acquire (this Semaphore semaphore, int permits) {
    for (int i = 0; i < permits; i++) {
        /*
         * If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block.
         * It tests the state of the wait handle and returns immediately.
         */
        if (!semaphore.WaitOne (0)) {
            semaphore.Release (i);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This can easily be modified to include a timeout. However, it would be more difficult to include blocking indefinitely (it would require signaling, else it would lead to a busy outer loop).